# Mysql grab row if condition is met, grab another if not

Tags: mysql

I am trying to LEFT JOIN a user's address to the user's name. I want to join their mailing address first, but if they don't have a mailing address then I want to join their home address, which they WILL have. Im struggling to find the correct way to go about this. Its an easy if/ else.. If they have an address_type = 'Mailing' select this row, if not, select the row where address_type = 'Home'. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like doing *two* left joins along with `COALESCE` to pick the desired address:

```
SELECT
    u.name,
    COALESCE(a1.address, a2.address) AS address
FROM user u
LEFT JOIN address a1
    ON u.id = a1.user_id AND
       a1.address_type = 'Mailing'
LEFT JOIN address a2
    ON u.id = a2.user_id AND
       a2.address_type = 'Home';
```

The above logic will choose the mailing address first for each user, if it be available.  Otherwise, it will default to using the home address.